# Sharepoint 2010 BCS - how to set the cache expiration?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I want to get the data from SAP " only once a day" and store it into Sharepoint 2010 BCS cache. How / Where do i do this setting which let BCS know that it should only query SAP data source once a day ?

Any help really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to interface with SAP through the `ISubscription` interface. From there you can set the expiration time for particular queries and associations. So for an `ISubscriptionQuery query` you can set one day expiration like so:

```
query.ExpireAfter = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
```

See this MSDN article for more information about setting these properties:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff464396.aspx#Y342

Answer (score 0):

Are you wanting the the **server** to retrieve the SAP data once a day and cache it? If so, the BCS cache will not help because the server only caches the BCS model.  The BCS data is cached on the client side. The ISubscription interface will work for the client but that means the SAP data will be queried once for each user.

Answer (score 0):

Please see these MSDN posts -

[**The cache is only available on the client, not the server.**](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010general/thread/43feb8b2-100a-4c78-b48f-17ae9bdda588).

[**BCS data caching in Search Server 2010**](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010general/thread/d40ba5e3-175d-468d-9fe8-ae77a8e0a33e)

Hope this helps :)